# Deciding about labels (Taxonomy in User Interface)

Tags: usability, usability-testing, mobile-application, labels

I work for a delivery company and we are creating a new section for our mobile app, which has the following features:

- Pending reviews of restaurants
- Order Status
- Order History
- Favorite restaurants

We are going to use cards for this view. The problem is that we are having some difficulties to create a name for that section. I was thinking about using open card sorting, just give this functionalities to the user and ask him to give a name for this area.

What do you guys think? Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your issue is? Are you trying to get people to start an order? Is this just a dashboard?

Comment: You're asking to confirm whether card sorting is a good methodology to help study participants pick menu labels that are most clear in relation to one another? This is the method I'd use too, but I bet there is also a way of asking the questions. Never done it, don't have a made-up reply, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If Order Status and Order History are about take-out orders, my suggestion for the section naming would be Eating Out & Takeaways.

If the Orders are about going out to restaurants yourself, then just Eating Out.

Comment: Actually those features are about food delivery and not take-out orders.
Same to Order History.

Order Status
- Making Order
- Order Confirmed
- Preparing the meal
- Delivering
- Order Delivered

Besides that, we have pending reviews too.

As all these features are user-based I was thinking "My iFood".

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. My iFood sounds maybe a bit too broad for me, but I guess it works better than anything else (like "My orders") here.

Answer (score 1):

Card sorting is a great method for you to use to get a better understanding of how your users group the information or functionality available to them. Doing the open card sort will also help generate ideas for what to label the groupings. You'll definitely want to include more cards from across your product.

There's also label criteria that you can rate possible ideas against.

Specific - label has one meaning only, user doesnt have to think.
Concise - includes just enough words to describe what's below, no more.
Comprehensive - inclusive of all the information.
Familiar - meaningful and understandable to the user.
Front-loaded - information-carrying word comes first.

Answer (score 0):

By "open card sorting", you mean to let participants create cards for the existing functionalities (including new as well as existing ones) and the group these cards, I assume.

Sounds like a good approach to me.

I am a little worried about your statement "we are creating a new section", which sounds like someone in your company decided these 4 new features are a new section. Since you didn't give more information about the existing features, it's hard to tell, but maybe these four new ones should be distributed to existing "sections" instead of making up a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a section Something like MY or Me .
Where you can put all User activities related fields under those.
In this case user can access all his (user related ) things under a single tab or new or whatever.
Hope this helps